# How to smooth histograms with bins 1, 2, 4, ... wide?

Tags: smoothing, histogram

Say I make histograms H1, H2, H4 ...of the same set of data
with bins 1, 2, 4 ... wide.
Then the bins containing a given $x$ have counts and averages

```
n1 av1 in H1,
n2 av2 in H2,
n4 av4 in H4 ...
```

How should one weight these to estimate data(x) ?
One possibility would be $\Sigma w_j \text{av}_j / \Sigma w_j$
with $w_j = n_j / j$, for the first two non-zero $n_j$.

The general goals are
to fill holes where bins are empty,
and to smooth bins with many data points.

(H2 etc. can either be built together with H1,
or on-the-fly from H1 as needed: a space-time tradeoff.)

Added, trying to clarify:
there are two related subquestions:

- local vs global:
  If almost all the terms in $\Sigma K( x_j\, \text{near}\, x )$ are 0, there must be a better way. (For 1D it hardly matters, but in 2D or 3D, $N^2$, $N^3$ get big quickly.)
  One way of finding $x_j$ near $x$ (to sum $K$ at those only) is to grow shells in a regular grid -- poor for clumpy or hole-y data.
  Another is to find $N_{\text{near}}$ nearest neighbours in a Kd tree -- but what should $N_{\text{near}}$ be ?
- adaptive histograms ?
  A method that adapts to clumpy data, as TINs (triangulations) adapt to terrains, would be nice.

(Years later) the magic words are "multiresolution" or "multiscale"; see e.g.
[scholar allintitle: (multiscale|multiresolution) (histogram | estimation)](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=allintitle%3a+%28multiscale|multiresolution%29+%28histogram+|+estimation%29&as_vis=1) .
Does anyone know of comparisons with conventional KDE on real data, 2d and up ?

Comment: What's wrong with conventional kernel density estimation?

Comment: Correct me, conventional KDE uses *all* the input data points for *each* estimate(x) -- quite unpractical for many points. I'm looking for ways to combine a) get some nearby points (a general problem), b) weight the values from this small sample

Comment: If you use a kernel with a finite support (e.g., the quadratic Epanechnikov kernel), then only nearby points contribute anything to a kde. Even with a Gaussian kernel, the contribution of points more than 3 bandwidths from x is negligible. I would definitely use kde rather than your proposed approach.

Comment: @Rob, thanks; I'll try to clarify the question, and split off "adaptive histograms" as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

I would see each histogram as a different model (parametrized by the width). Fitting a smoothing spline or some other kind of smoother for each of the models is simple.

You can then do model selection (such as cross-validation) to choose the histogram width that gives the best results, or do model stacking to fit least-squares weights on the models.

However, why not directly smooth the data instead of clustering it into histogram bars first? There are finite-window width kernels that don't use the entire dataset for prediction at a given point. Practicality and speed depends on what you are really trying to obtain, but I am sure there exist simpler solutions.

Comment: Agree with last para. The Gaussian kernel uses all the data points but other commonly-used kernels (Epanechnikov, biweight, cosine, Parzen, triangular, ...) are finite-width, i.e. they are defined to be zero outside a finite interval. R's density() function defaults to Gaussian but Stata's -kdensity- command defaults to Epanechnikov.